# Spring boot WebSockets TextWebSocketHandler not working with json messges

Tags: java, spring-boot, websocket

I have added web sockets to my app for transmitting messages and make an interactive app.

What I need to transmit with web-sockets is the POJO Objects. But, the `TextWebSocketHandler` is not working and not sending messages. When I test the web sockets, I get:

> WebSocket is already in CLOSING or CLOSED state.

I don't know if it work but I think the size of the messages is stopping the web socket.

Code:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocket
public class WebsocketConfig implements WebSocketConfigurer{
    @Bean
    public WebSocketHandler myMessageHandler() {
        return new MyMessageHandler();
    }


    @Override
    public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addHandler(myMessageHandler(), "/my-websocket-endpoint");
    }

}

public class MyMessageHandler extends TextWebSocketHandler {

    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public void afterConnectionClosed(WebSocketSession session, CloseStatus status) throws Exception {
        // The WebSocket has been closed
    }

    @Override
    public void afterConnectionEstablished(WebSocketSession session) throws Exception {
        // The WebSocket has been opened
        // I might save this session object so that I can send messages to it outside of this method

        // Let's send the first message
        Gson gson=new Gson();
        session.sendMessage(new TextMessage(gson.toJson(findall())));
    }

    @Override
    protected void handleTextMessage(WebSocketSession session, TextMessage textMessage) throws Exception {
        // A message has been received

            Gson gson=new Gson();
            session.sendMessage(new TextMessage(gson.toJson(findall())));

    }

    public List<User> findall(){

        return userRepository.findAll();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Trying removing the throws Exception in the methods where you use the json parsing, then apply the try and catch around the parsing operation and deal with the exception you might encounter.